# Deploying website on web hosting

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

I have created one ASP.net website. I have web hosting and have ftp access for deploying the website. When I deploy or we can say copy the publish of my website then it is working fine **www.myweb.in**. However I want to make the website link structure as **www.myweb.in/betav1**. I have created the `betav1` folder on root and copied all my publish contents to it but seems it's not working.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure that the webhoster supports asp.net?

Comment: it is showing error in web.config file at "<authentication mode="Windows"/>". and yes the webhoster supports asp.net as when i copy all contents to root directory, the website is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly because your `betav1` folder that you created is not configured as an application in IIS or it is not a virtual directory.

Your website will be pointing to a folder in the server which is configured as a virtual directory. Since the sub folder is created by you, it will not be marked as a virtual directory or as an application in the server. So high chances that this is the issue.

To configure this folder as an "Application" you will need to go to its properties and click on create button to configure it as an application.

Since its a remote server, you should be asking your service provider for this. Once you do this your problem will most probably be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get a Virtual Directory setup under your domain. Maybe the hosting provider will be able to give you these permissions. Check your documents / instruction on how to manager these.

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to know how to configure Virtual Directories on IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

there could be many factors to answer why its not working.

app_code,bin_app_data folders MUST be under main ROOT of your website. your web.config is configured properly for web host? You links in web application are formated correctly to start with /betav1?